# SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2017 - RESTORE DATABASE FAILS

Tags: backup, database, sql-server, restore

I backup a database using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9.1 and then I try to restore the backup but it fails with the following message.

Thank you very much for helping.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The operating system returned the error '32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DbName.mdf'. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: Have you used a utility to determine what other process is using the file?

Comment: Nothing is using the backup file DbName.bak. I don't think the problem is about that. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to restore the database to the same server where the original database is still online or to a new server? Are you restoring using the restore wizard or a restore script?

Comment: Same server. I am just doing a backup and then I am trying to restore it for testing to see if it works. Thanks